# ¿Qué sucede si cambio las extensiones de mis archivos en mi proyecto de Js a Jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-navigation, jsx

¿Qué sucede si cambio las extensiones de mis archivos en mi proyecto de Js a Jsx?.
¿Cuándo debería usar una extensión u otra?

Como pueden observar soy muy nuevo en React. :)

Comment: Si escribes solamente código en javascript puro y plano entonces tus archivos deben tener de extensión .JS, por el contrario si usas está [sintaxis](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) entonces tus archivos deben tener extensión .jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es necesario que los archivos tengan `.jsx` como extensión. De hecho, el equipo de [React decidió utilizar extensión de archivos `.js` como predeterminada](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3582#issuecomment-89411479). Es por esto que cuando inicializamos un nuevo proyecto con [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/) las extensiones de archivo JavaScript terminan en `.js`.

La realidad es que el module bundler (Webpack) transpila los archivos usando [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) y se encarga automáticamente de detectar qué archivos JavaScript tienen JSX.

**TLDR**: La convención general es usar `.js` para proyectos que usan React, pero si usas `.jsx` también va a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

React por defecto te va a compilar tanto los archivos `js` como `jsx` entre otros como:

```
js  -> Archivos JavaScript
mjs -> Modulos EcmaScript 
jsx -> Extensión de la sintaxis de JavaScript(nos permite mezclar JS y HTML y XML)
ts  -> TypeScript
tsx -> Igual que jsx solo que es usado con TypeScript
```

> Puedes ver más [aquí](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L393)

Como comento @BetaM, no debes usar la extensión `js` cuando estas usando una sintaxis como `JSX` aparte de que es mala practica, también te puede dar problemas en el futuro.

Básicamente usa `js` solo cuando tengas código puro de JavaScript y `jsx` cuando vayas a mezclar cosas como html, css o XML. Lo mismo pasa con otras extensiones

Comment: Este tipo de código mezcla html y javascript y todo React es así. Por lo que dices, todos los archivos deberían ser jsx. Si embargo la respuesta de Juan Marco tiene lógica. Parece que está convergiendo todo hacia JS.  <div className="">
                  <i className="material-icons text-danger"
                    onClick={() => onDeleteLink(link.id)}>
                    close
                  </i>
                  <i className="material-icons"
                    onClick={() => setCurrentId(link.id)}>
                    create
                  </i>

Comment: No digo que todos los archivos deben de ser jsx, si no que usa la extensión que sea mas adecuada según el código que vaya a escribir